# Masonry grid not showing properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

here i am trying to get the masonry grid to my bootstrap row values. but when i initiate the masonry grid i am getting the grid with lots of space between the items in below rows. how can i resolve this?

FULL HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .grid-item {width:400px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=17"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=17" class="productname">Campingaz Expert Plus Gas Barbecue</a><br><br><span class="price">₹7995/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">17800</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=15"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=15" class="productname">Milagrow Swimming Pool Robot : RoboPhelps</a><br><br><span class="price">₹29709/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">150000</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 8 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=33"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=33" class="productname">Stanley Socket Set</a><br><br><span class="price">₹0/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">3</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=36"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=36" class="productname">Deemark Portable Home Spa Havvy Massager</a><br><br><span class="price">₹0/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">3</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">1 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=4"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=4" class="productname">Yamaha 01V96i Digital Mixer</a><br><br><span class="price">₹88630/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">227900</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=17"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=17" class="productname">Campingaz Expert Plus Gas Barbecue</a><br><br><span class="price">₹7995/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">17800</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=15"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=15" class="productname">Milagrow Swimming Pool Robot : RoboPhelps</a><br><br><span class="price">₹29709/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">150000</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 8 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=33"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=33" class="productname">Stanley Socket Set</a><br><br><span class="price">₹0/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">3</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=36"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=36" class="productname">Deemark Portable Home Spa Havvy Massager</a><br><br><span class="price">₹0/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">3</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">1 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 item"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body"><a href="product-description.php?product_id=4"><br><br><img class="product_listing_img img-responsive" src="http://www.arredatutto.com/en/images/icecat/21892178-52336.jpg"><br></a><a href="product-description.php?product_id=4" class="productname">Yamaha 01V96i Digital Mixer</a><br><br><span class="price">₹88630/-</span><h4><span>₹<strike class="maxprice">227900</strike></span></h4><span class="owners">0 of 4 owners reached</span><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="proposed by ashissin" class="proposer_icon"><img class="img-responsive" src="libraries/images/avatars/avatar-1.png"></span><a href="mycart.php" class="buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart</a></div></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('.grid').masonry({
              itemSelector: '.grid-item',
              columnWidth: 400
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the output i am getting right now:[image]

Comment: It seems like Masonry is not initialised or working at all—the layout is exactly what you'd get when you have Masonry turned off. Check your console log. What does it say?

Comment: Also you probably want to add rows to your markup in the appropriate places so that the layout works when js is not turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/132/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
  });
});
```

**EDIT** Use latest version of JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Masonry is not initialized. Also, ***itemSelector*** cannot be ***.grid-item***, but only ***.item***. Fix it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var container = document.querySelector('.grid');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        // options
        columnWidth: 400,
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
});
```

Here's [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7sj2qxg/3/). I hope it helps.